# How to modify the length of the select box

Tags: html, css, combobox

Do you know how to modify the length of the select (combo) box.

Supposed that I have the following combo box:
http://jsfiddle.net/nxhoaf/NeVyf/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<select>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I modify its length. I.e: When I click on expand button, the box should display all 20 results instead of 19. (The scroll should disappear here)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible, the only way to achieve what you want is to used a styled select which can be done using jQuery

Comment: Could you give me an example ?

Comment: I've used this one in the past: https://code.google.com/p/lnet/wiki/jQueryStyledSelectOverview

Answer (score 0):

There is a size attribute in HTML5
`<select size="20">`

Comment: ...Which doesn't do what you want, ignore that